# How can I detect if user has subscribed Memberpress product already

Tags: php, wordpress, membership

How can I detect if user has already bought a memberpress product.

I'm searching something like this:

```
if(have_subscription){ 
   //code to add button
}else{
   // code to add something else
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should be pretty straight forward using MemberPress' built in capabilities:

```
if(current_user_can('memberpress_authorized')) {
  // Do authorized only stuff here
}
else {
  // Do unauthorized stuff here
}
```

MemberPress also adds capabilities for each MemberPress Membership so you could also do something like this:

```
if(current_user_can('memberpress_product_authorized_123')) {
  // Do authorized only stuff here
}
else {
  // Do unauthorized stuff here
}
```

In the second example the number 123 is the id of the MemberPress membership.

Comment: is there a list womewhere with what capabillities that are available for use?

Comment: Any way to check the active plan?  Or return "123"?

Answer (score 10):

The answer from 2015 didn't work for me but is a top search result. I thought I should share the result of my search here for others in the future.

Also, I think that "product_authorized" capability only checked if a purchase was made, not verifying the expiration date.

So here is how MemberPress determines if active, inactive, or none:

```
$mepr_user = new MeprUser( $user_id );

if( $mepr_user->is_active() ) {
    // Active
}else if($mepr_user->has_expired()) {
    // Expired
}else {
    // Never a member
}
```

`has_expired()` can return true even if the user is active from a separate transaction so don't rely on that alone.

If you need to **check a specific membership** you can use the following:

```
$user_id = 123;
$membership_id = 5000;

$mepr_user = new MeprUser( $user_id );

$mepr_user->is_already_subscribed_to( $membership_id ); // true or false

// OR

$mepr_user->is_active_on_membership( $membership_id ); // true or false
```

`is_already_subscribed_to()` accepts only a product id

`is_active_on_membership()` accepts any of: product id, MeprProduct, MeprTransaction, or MeprSubscription

You can also get all of a user's active subscriptions with:

```
$mepr_user->active_product_subscriptions( 'ids' ); // return array of ids
```

Answer (score -5):

Open your WordPress website and:

- Select `Plugins > Add New`
- Click on `Upload Plugin > Choose file`
- Select the `MemberPress` plugin from your saved files
- Click `Install Plugin > Activate`

You will now find `MemberPress` has been added to your WordPress dashboard.
This should help.

Comment: This is not an answer. The question is completely unrelated to "how to install Memberpress plugin in Wordpress"